# CRM 2011 custom Plugin passing parameters to processes

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

We are trying to automate a few things in CRM and I have an idea about how to go about it while still allowing customizations from the Process section in CRM Settings.

The problem: We receive a lot of E-mails from an account that are added to a Queue. This queue fills up faster than we can clear it. Most of these E-mails have a standard format and the user only has to read a few lines of the the E-mail body to figure out what to do. There's a total of 6 different workflows that the user would do. These haven't been implemented.

Reading the documentation of CRM, I figured that I would need a custom Plug-in that would parse the E-mail body, and trigger a workflow in CRM according to the values in the E-mail. I also need some of the values that the E-mail contains to be passed to the workflow. I already have the Plug-in setup to do this.

The problem I run into is creating a process which takes in custom parameters passed over by the Plug-in I created. I need to access these values in the front-end (one of the Processes in CRM Settings). Is this possible? If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you used a Plugin to kick-off this automation instead of a Custom Workflow (which is a Process)? You could perform the parsing of the E-mail inside your Custom Workflow, and use its InOutArgument properties to pass values into subsequent child workflows.

Definition: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984(v=crm.5).aspx

Sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/gg334455(v=crm.5).aspx

Comment: Doh! Wow ok, I completely missed that. I started reading the documentation and it seemed like the Plug-in would be the ideal solution for parsing the E-mail. And reading about the "Workflow" (Process) and the Workflow activity confused me because of the nomenclature they use in the docs.